# HttpWebRequest, post method

Tags: php, post, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7.1

I have a small problem with HttpWebRequest in my wp 7.1 application. The application sends some game stats data to the php server by POST -method, but server doesn't fetch it. **The $_POST array stays empty.** With the aid of the WireShark I can see the data is in the packet sent to the server, but server doesn't receive any.

Here is the code of the method by which the data is sent:

```
    private void SendStatisticsToServer()
    {
        if (this.stat.Name == String.Empty || Object.ReferenceEquals(this.stat.Name, null))
        {
            this.OnEmptyNameEvent();
        }
        else
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ADDRESS) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/plain";
            request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;

            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallBack), request);
        }
    }

    private void GetRequestStreamCallBack(IAsyncResult requestRes)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("user=");
        builder.Append(this.stat.Name);
        builder.Append("&won=");
        builder.Append(this.stat.Won == true ? "1" : "0");
        builder.Append("&scores=");
        builder.Append(this.stat.Scores.ToString());

        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());

        HttpWebRequest request = requestRes.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(requestRes);
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult requestRes)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = requestRes.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

        HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(requestRes) as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(stream);
        String responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close();
        streamRead.Close();

        response.Close();
        this.OnExitButtonPressedEvent(ButtonType.Exit);
    }
```

(I'm sorry for the code with no comments, but I think it's self-explanatory )

As you can see, it's almost copy-past from the msdn.

And here is the php -server code:

```
    <?php
     header('Content-type: text/plain'); 
     // HTTP/1.1
     header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
     // HTTP/1.0
     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     $logfile = 'postdata.txt';
     $firstData = $_POST["user"];
     $secondData = $_POST["won"];
     $thirdData = $_POST["scores"];
     $file = fopen($logfile, "a+");

     fwrite($file, "Post received - data: firstData=". $firstData . "   
     secondData=" . $secondData . " thirdData=" . $thirdData . "\r\n");
     fclose($file);

     ?>
```

As you can see, this server doesn't do much - only receiving the data and pushing it into the log -file.

it is definitely not a server's bug, since the old application written in Qt works fine under the same conditions and the $_POST array is not empty.

Could you, please, tell me, where could be a possible error?

The target platform is WP 7.1.

Thank you beforehand for your answers.

Comment: You say you looked at it with wireshark, what's the server response?

Comment: @Pete Yes, I used wireshark for checking the packet's content. The server response is HTTP/1.1 200 OK according to wireshark. I got the same response in the application too(response.StatusCode always returns OK)

Comment: Can you post the URL and headers that wireshark sees?

Comment: @Pete Yes, sure. Have a look at my first post under the "UPDATE:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have to do this as an answer, but I'm not entirely sure this is correct. I believe for a text/plain post, the format of the parameters is:

```
user=d
won=1
scores=3
```

If the you do application/x-www-form-urlencoded, then you would go with

```
user=d&won=1&scores=3
```

There's also a possibility PHP doesn't support text/plain.

Comment: That's a bit odd, I've try to send the only parameter to the server and result is still the same. The $_POST array is empty.

Comment: I have to say you THANK YOU, man. Based on your answer, I made the only change in the app and it's working now!

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

A small alteration was done on the server side too:

header('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');